# Angular 5 download excel file from web api ClosedXml

Tags: angular, http

I am trying to download an excel file generated by my web api in my angular application. The application was first written in angularJS, and everything works fine over there. Now I am migrating the app to Angular 5 and it also works fine, but I get an error saying: type '"arraybuffer"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.

It uses HttpClient

```
this.http.post<any>(`${this.appConfig.api}/users`, users, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
  .subscribe(
    (next: ArrayBuffer) => {
      console.log(next);
      const file: Blob = new Blob([next], { type: 'application/xlsx' });
      saveAs(file, `Rapport users.xlsx`);
    }
  )
```

How can i get rid of the error?

Comment: Can you remove  {responseType: 'arraybuffer'} from the http post request and check

Comment: The excel file is corrupt if I remove that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed {responseType: 'arraybuffer'} to {responseType: 'arraybuffer' as 'json'}

Answer (score 1):

Try this out from the angular documentation. [Link](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data)

```
this.http.get(`${this.appConfig.api}/users`, {responseType: 'blob'})
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          console.log(data);
          const file: Blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/xlsx' });
          saveAs(file, `Rapport users.xlsx`);
        }
      )
```